# Could not find resource assembly error when i try to pass data from terminal to webservice

Tags: c#, web-services, windows-mobile

i try to pass data (string) from terminal (windows mobile) to webservice

i have good connection and i got this error:

```
Could not find resource assembly
```

thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

That means there's an error in your windows mobile application. It searches for the right exception, but can't find it : http://blogs.msdn.com/b/netcfteam/archive/2004/08/06/210232.aspx